# Can a website track keystrokes like OS or browser related keybind pressing?

Tags: websites, screen-capture

There are several ways to track how a user interacts with a website, including mouse position and clicks.

Does the same apply to taking screenshots though? Can a website track browser or system related hotkeys?

For example, which of the following would reveal either clicks or keystrokes (assuming they were pressed while the website had been selected)?

- Pressing <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> then clicking to select the area I need to take a screenshot of.
- <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab on Firefox (or any other Firefox keybind).
- Opening the command line using keybinds.

Comment: Well, it depends on the browser I guess. You can check using this [website](https://keycode.info/). Try the key sequences you are concerned about. If the page can register the last key of the sequence, then that sequence can definitely be tracked. Otherwise, it *probably* can't.